# Doctrine - how select fields to return from the query (in Symfony2)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

So imagine a basic query:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT x FROM MyBundle:MyEntity x'
);

$result = $query->getResult();
```

How do I select which fields to return? I was a bit thrown at the SELECT part as this is very different from SQL's SELECT (fields) from table. In fact it looks a bit odd to me, why not just do this similar to SQL?

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM MyBundle:MyEntity
```

Anyway, how would I limit to a set list of fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [Doctrine partial object](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html):

```
$q = $em->createQuery("select partial u.{id,name} from MyApp\Domain\User u");
```